# int too large, cannot use mod (%) for double and int

Tags: c++, types

Here's my code to find the prime factors of a number :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long int a, b, c, d = 0, f;
    int w = 0;

    f = 13195;

    for(a = 3; a < 100; a++)
    {
        w = f % a;

        if(w == 0)
        {
            for(b = 2; b < a; b++)
            {
                d = 0;
                c = a % b;
                if(c == 0)
                {
                    d++;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(d == 0)
                cout << a << " is a prime\n";
        }
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

`f` is the number to be checked. I have to check a 12 digit number, but I cannot use `double` and `long int` as `%` cannot act on both together. What can I do instead?

Comment: You need to check for factors out to sqrt(f) = 114

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `long long` is a larger data type that can handle 64-bit (>12 digit) numbers. Using that should work.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you're not allowed to use `long long` as mentioned in another answer, you can simulate `%` on doubles:

```
c = a - floor(a / b) * b;
```

If `a` and `b` are less than about 2**52 (4503599627370496) this should work.